# Securing a Temporary Access Key for Encrypted Data

Tags: security, encryption

I am building a secure data store that can share secure information between a number of authenticated users, as well as letting unauthenticated users check data into the secure data store without making it public or divulging its contents.

Currently, the data is encrypted with a 1024-bit key, and has an associated RSA (2048-bit) Key Pair (with the Private Key being encrypted by the 1024-bit key). This means that if people want to check data in, then can use the RSA keys.

The 1024-bit key is also encrypted using User Secrets that are specific to each user, completely private, and randomly generated at the onset (or reset when requested). This means that the users can access the data without the key being public.

The final bit is storing the Users Secret. The secret itself is encrypted using another RSA (also with a 2048-bit key) Key Pair. The Public Key is associated with the user, and the Private Key is encrypted using their login Password.

When it comes to actually logging in, the user's username and password is validated, then a unique token is returned to the browser that will authorize it as a specific user.

At the login point, if it's valid, the password will be used to decrypt the RSA private key, so that the User Secret can be recovered.

But the user's password is only available to the system at one time, so I was going to use that moment to get the Users Secret and store it somewhere where it is available to the current login session, but no-one else.

Although I could store it in a separate database that would encrypt it (lets say with the Access Token) that would be lost when the user signs out, my worry is that if someone tries to break into the system when someone is logged in, they could recover the secret, and therefore, the rest of the data.

Does anyone have any ideas or references to implementations that can protect the User Secret from access by everyone except for the Session?

Comment: One potential fix I can think of would be to encrypt the UserSecret with another secret, and that secret isn't stored in the database, but in the user browsers cookie. Sure it would have to employ SSL, but its secure data, and this would be overkill for such a HUGE security gap